# Estouro de layout no perfil

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design, layout

Veja a aba de votos escorregando para a linha de baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso não acontecia quando tinha menos informações na linha.

Comment: Acontece quando tem notificação nas abas; se você zerar as notificações, fica normal. Vai ter de espremer alguma coisa pra resolver...

Comment: Eu gosto de espaço entre as coisas, mas acho que dá pra dar uma espremidinha nos paddings. Não sei se isso é geral do SO, mas creio que dê pra ajustar. Português realmente usa palavras maiores.

Comment: Alguém pode verificar se isso foi resolvido?

Comment: @Gabe Ao que parece, foi sim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apercebi-me de uma diferença bem substancial entre o SOEN e o SOPT no que respeita à formatação dos separadores:

## SOEN

- O separador que se encontra ativo está com um corpo de letra de 15 pixeis:

  [image: Valores calculados pelo Firefox]
- Os separadores inativos estão com um corpo de letra de 11 pixeis:

  [image: Valores calculados pelo Firefox]

Aqui temos um corpo de letra razoavelmente pequeno para separadores inativos, e um maior para o separador ativo.

## SOPT

- O separador que se encontra ativo está com um corpo de letra de 13 pixeis:

  [image: Valores calculados pelo Firefox]
- Os separadores inativos estão com um corpo de letra de 13 pixeis:

  [image: Valores calculados pelo Firefox]

Aqui temos um corpo de letra igual para separadores inativos e separador ativo.

---

A questão é que dada a quantidade de informação a colocar nos separadores e dado o número de separadores em uso, o corpo de letra deve ser ajustado para não "roubar" tanto espaço e permitir que o layout fique em condições.

Com um corpo de letra de 12 pixeis, o layout já parece comportar-se de forma decente e ainda sobra algum espaço:

[image: Alteração para corpo de letra 12px]

Mas podemos ser minuciosos e aplicar o mesmo corpo de letra que é utilizado no SOEN de +/- 11px, ficando assim uma boa margem de manobra para ter mais legendas azuis com contagens.