# Layout quebrado nas abas de classificações de perguntas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

Nesta página: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=newest&pageSize=15

Atualmente renderiza desta forma no Chrome 32:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que isto acontece pois o texto "Perguntas com tags" e as abas deveriam aparecer na mesma linha, mas há uma quebra de linha automática indesejada devido ao conteúdo não caber em uma única linha.

É possível comprovar isto removendo uma das abas (neste exemplo removi a aba "apresentado"):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não tenho nenhuma sugestão em particular para concertar. Talvez utilizar traduções mais curtas (e possivelmente um `padding` menor). Acredito que ocultar abas ou estender o layout seriam soluções desnecessariamente complexas.

Relacionado: [Estouro de layout no perfil](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258/1944) (problema com abas em outra página)

Comment: Eu comentei com a equipe de design sobre isso essa semana. Acontece sempre que a tag tem alguma pergunta com gratificação. Eles estão de olho.

Comment: @Gabe obrigado pela resposta rápida, bom saber que já estavam cientes deste problema. `=]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por favor, desculpe a minha escrita em português. Sou um americano com a família no sul do Brasil, em Santa Catarina.

Uma das duas respostas que eu estou migrando de: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228308/249307

O `<h1>` (título) se destina a ser alinhadas horizontalmente com `<div id="tabs">` (barra de abas), porém os `<a>`-tags (abas) de texto contém mais caracteres do que o pretendido pela concepção. Largura de cada guia é baseado em caracteres e, cumulativamente, a largura chega a ser maior do que a largura entre o título, à esquerda, e no fim de englobar `<div class="subheader">`-tag (subcabeçalho).

Esta condição faz com que a barra de abas para transbordar o subcabeçalho que está definido para 34px. No entanto, a fronteira 1px horizontais destinam-se a estar na parte inferior da barra de abas é definido no sub-cabeçalho, e por isso mantém-se inalterado, enquanto a barra de abas mergulha abaixo.

Solução possível é para acomodar a barra de abas, ajustando a altura do subcabeçalho, mas desde que as abas parecem ser definido dinamicamente isso pode não ser óptimo:

```
<style>
  .subheader {height: 64px;}
</style>
```

Desde sites de Stack Exchange usam jQuery, essa correção pode ser aplicado da seguinte forma:

```
<script>
  $('.subheader').css('height', 64);
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Truncar o texto abas com CSS:

```
<style>
  #tabs a {
    max-width: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

O mesmo CSS acima aplicada com jQuery:

```
<script>
  $('#tabs a').css({'max-width':'50px', 'white-space':'nowrap', 'text-overflow':'ellipsis', 'overflow':'hidden'});
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas. Em minha opinião, a outra resposta é a melhor opção, visto que esta opção não é muito "acessível" -- os textos resumidos não são claros o suficiente e depender de um atributo `title` é longe da melhor opção. Aceitei a sua outra resposta. `=]`