# Tradução de "Perguntas com Tags"

Tags: bug, tradução

No processo de resolver os bugs antigos do site, cheguei (finalmente) [nesse aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/915):

[image: Bug de alinhamento]

O problema é de CSS, mas o texto **Perguntas com tags** além de errado, é bem maior do que poderia ser o que atrapalha ainda mais a consertar o erro. Precisamos de uma alternativa

Answer (score 4):

"Perguntas com tags" não é uma boa tradução para "Tagged Questions". Então eu proponho usar: ***Perguntas da tag***

É bem menor e portanto ia precisar de menos ajustes para consertar o problema.